# Enumerate all files in a container and copy each file in a foreach

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

Need to load all .csv files in Azure Blob Container into SQL database.

Tried using a wild card `*.*` on the filename in the dataset which uses the linked service that connects to the blob and outputting the itemName in the Get Meta Data activity.

When executing in debug a list of filenames is not returned in the Output window. When referencing the parameter with an expression it is stated that the type is String not collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of task, I use the [Get Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) activity and process the results with a [For Each](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity) activity. Inside the For Each activity, you can have a simple Copy activity to copy the CSV files to SQL tables, or if the work is more complex you can use Data Flow.

Some useful tips:

1. In the Get Metadata activity, under the DataSet tab > "Field list", select the "Child Items" option:

[image]

2. I recommend adding a "Filter" activity after the Get Metadata to ensure that you are only processing files, and optionally even expected extensions. You do this in the Settings tab like so:

[image]

3. In the For Each activity, on the Settings tab, set the Items based on the output of the Filter activity:

[image]

4. Inside the For Each, at the activity level, you reference the instance by "@item().name":

[image]

Here's what one of my production pipelines that implements this pattern looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For you needs, you could get an idea of [LookUp Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity).

> Lookup activity can retrieve a dataset from any of the Azure Data
>   Factory-supported data sources. Use it in the following scenario:
>
> Dynamically determine which objects to operate on in a subsequent
>   activity, instead of hard coding the object name. Some object examples
>   are files and tables.

For example, my container has 2  csv files in `test` container:

[image]

[image]

Configure a blob storage dataset :

[image]

Configure Lookup Activity:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually using `*.*`?  That may be too vague for the system to interpret.  Maybe you can try something a little more descriptive, like this, `???20190101.json`, or whatever matches the patters of your data-sets.

I encountered a weird problem a couple weeks ago, whereby I was using the wildcard character to iterate through a bunch of files.  I was always starting on row 3 and as luck would have it, some files didn't have a row 3.  A handful of files had metadata in row 1, field names in row 2, and no row 3.  So, I was getting some weird errors.  I changed the line start to be row 2 and everything worked fine after that.

Also, check out the link below.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/data-factory-supports-wildcard-file-filter-for-copy-activity/